# Avoiding layout shift with font replacement?

Tags: css, fonts

I'm trying to resolve a layout-shift issue that is being caused by font-replacement.

**Issue:**

- Mainly regarding mobile / responsive layout
- The font causes the draw sizes to change causing a CLS issue (0.222) according to lighthouse.
- When the font loads some of text wraps to an additional line, I think this is causing the bulk of the CLS.
- Attempting to resolve the CLS issue, without a large increase in FCP or LCP.

**Implementation:**

- Currently just have the font linked in the header, using value of swap.
- If i preconnect to the URL and then preload the font family, It resolves the CLS issue. (code sample below)
- Now I take an increase in LCP of 0.3 (according to lighthouse again)

  ```
       <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" crossorigin>
       <link rel="preload" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans&display=swap" as="style">
  ```

**Questions:**

- Is there any way to allow to font to replace at best-effort, so it does not impact the FCP or LCP while resolving the CLS issue?
- It seems i'm faced with a pick-your-issue, either take the increase in LCP, CLS, or remove the font altogether?
- Is there an advantage to loading the entire font-family, instead of just the weights needed? (In real-world is it possible the user has the font family cached?) I'm loading *family=Open+Sans:300,400,500,700*, would I benefit from simply loading *family=Open+Sans*

Performance trace - First image is production site, notice the CLS issue. 2nd image resolves the CLS issue, but i increase the LCP and FCP.

[image: Prod - CLS Issue]
[image: Stage - CLS Resolved]

Comment: do you  try `clamp(MIN, VAL, MAX)` a CSS property, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clamp()

Comment: FWIW seeing exactly the same issue. Fixing one just makes the other worse. Lighthouse is the devil.